# Using Alchemy Entity Extraction to retrieve JSON output

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, alchemyapi

I am running the `EntityTest.java` file from the Alchemy API Java SDK which can be found [here](https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_java). The programs works just fine, **but it seems there is no way to change output format to JSON.**

I have tried executing this code-

```
// Create an AlchemyAPI object.
        AlchemyAPI alchemyObj = AlchemyAPI.GetInstanceFromFile("api_key.txt");
        
        // Force the output type to be JSON
        AlchemyAPI_NamedEntityParams params = new AlchemyAPI_NamedEntityParams();
        params.setOutputMode("json");

        // Extract a ranked list of named entities for a web URL.
        Document doc = alchemyObj.URLGetRankedNamedEntities("http://www.techcrunch.com/", params);
        System.out.println(getStringFromDocument(doc));
```

But the code throws a RunTimeException, and prints the following on console-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid setting json for parameter outputMode
    at com.alchemyapi.api.AlchemyAPI_Params.setOutputMode(AlchemyAPI_Params.java:42)
    at com.alchemyapi.test.EntityTest.main(EntityTest.java:29)
```

Also, here is the `setOutputCode` method from AlchemyAPI_Params.java file-

```
public void setOutputMode(String outputMode) {
        if( !outputMode.equals(AlchemyAPI_Params.OUTPUT_XML) && !outputMode.equals(OUTPUT_RDF) ) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid setting " + outputMode + " for parameter outputMode");
        }
        this.outputMode = outputMode;
    }
```

As is evident from the code, **it seems that the only 2 acceptable output formats are XML and RDF.** Is that so?? Is there no way the get the output in JSON?

Can anybody please help me out regarding that??

Comment: as i see it you will need to provide this functionality yourself...

Comment: Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by resorting to a completely different approach. Instead of using the already available Java SDK, I made an HTTP connection to the endpoint of URLGetRankedNamedEntities API, and retrieved the response.

Here is a code sample that demonstrates how to do this-

```
URL urlObj = new URL("http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/url/URLGetRankedNamedEntities?apikey=" + API_KEY_HERE + "&url=http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/04/08/web-scraping-with-nodejs/&outputMode=json");
System.out.println(urlObj.toString() + "\n");

URLConnection connection = urlObj.openConnection();
connection.connect();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=  null) {
    builder.append(line + "\n");
}

System.out.println(builder);
```

Similar endpoints are avaliable for other APIs as well, which can found [here](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add new constant : OUTPUT_JSON in AlchemyAPI_Params and modify the setOutputMode method to accept it.

After that in AlchemyAPI  :

You will need to modify the doRequest method with a the new OUTPUT_JSON case.

You can use :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

to create the new content.

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for the help @alias_boubou, but I used a completely different approach towards it, and finally did it... :) :)